# Alternative to speed up Python for loop with joins

Tags: python, pandas, loops, join, merge

I am working with a large dataframe (circa 7 mil records) and need to iterate some values over a unique subset of that.
Say, my original dataframe "df" has columns user_id, name, address, date and product , whilst my subset dataframe "s" (which in reality is about 30k rows), is a list of unique the products in "df".

I want to find the cross probability of buying 2 given products (a bit what is used in recommendation algorithms), however in doing so I am working with a loop with a set of simple data manipulation steps - pivot table would be nice but the dataset appears to be too large.

I tried a loop (see code below), however there are circa 30k iterations which from my review on timings would lead to circa 48-55 hours of calculation.
Apart from trying the aforementioned pivot code, which just crashes Python.
I also tried with list comprehensions and a function but the performance increases only marginally, without real meaning.

The loop I have is:

```
out = []
for s in product :

 o = pd.DataFrame(df["name"].loc[df["product_code"] == s])
 c = pd.merge(df, o, on="name")

 d = c.loc[c['product_code']!=i]

 product_cts = d.groupby('item_code') ['name'].count().sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index(name ='product_counts')

 product_cts["cross_prob"] = product_cts["product_counts"]/len(o)
 product_cts["origin_product"] = s

 out.append(product_cts)
```

Any ideas on how to re-engineer this or increase the performance?

Comment: Don't you think this would be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com, considering that your code actually works fine?

Comment: @RandomDavis, Actually, questions involving performance improvement are in-scope for SO. Having said this, we need more information from OP, e.g. a sample input dataframe we can benchmark against *ourselves*. As it stands, there's no [mcve].